# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException : Exception parsing document: template="result", line 28 - column 23

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

I am using spring boot, thymeleaf and javascript

**controller**

```
    package demo;        
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    @Controller
    class TestController implements ErrorController{
        protected Connection conn;
        private static final String PATH = "/error";

        public TestController() {
            super();

        }
            // En cas d'érreur
            @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
            public String error() {
                System.err.println("test1");
                return "Error";
            }
            @Override
            public String getErrorPath() {
                System.err.println("test2");
                return PATH;
            }
        // Afficher le formulaire de création de base de données

        @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String test(Model model){
            try {

            DetailsDatabase db=new DetailsDatabase();

            model.addAttribute("db",new DetailsDatabase());

            System.out.println(model);

            } catch (Exception {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.err.println("test3");
            return "hello";

        }

          @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.POST)
            public String DatabaseSubmit(@ModelAttribute DetailsDatabase db, Model model) {
                model.addAttribute("db",db);


try {
    // on crée la base et on récupère une Connection
        this.conn=SingletonConnection.getConnection();
        Statement ps1=conn.createStatement();
        ps1.execute("CREATE DATABASE "+db.getDatabase_Name());
        ps1.close();



} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
System.err.println("test5");
return "result";
        }
     // @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)

       /*String url=SingletonConnection.getUrl()+"/"+db.getDatabase_Name()+"";
        SingletonConnection.setConnection(DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root",""));
          this.conn=SingletonConnection.getConnection();
            Statement ps2=conn.createStatement();       
            System.err.println("test4");
              Statement ps=conn.createStatement();
              String req="CREATE TABLE " +db.getTable_Name()+" ("+db.getField()+" "+db.getType()+"("+db.getSize()+")" +" "+db.getNullabilité()+")";
             System.err.println(req);
              ps.execute(req);   
               ps2.close();*/
}
```

Here's my principal form: hello.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Creating database: Handing Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" ></meta>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/test}" th:object="${db}" method="post">
        <p>Database_Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{Database_Name}" /></p>
        <p>columns_number <input type="text" th:field="*{columns_number}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and here's my second form: result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handing Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <p th:text="'columns_number: ' + ${db.columns_number}" />
    <h3>Création de la base de données</h3>
    <p>Table_name: <input type="text" th:field="${db.table_Name}" /></p>
<table id='tablona' border='1px'>
        <tr>
        <th>field</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>null</th>
                </tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
            for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
                $('<tr>'+
                '<td><input id="field" type="text" name="field'+i+'"  maxlength="255"  required="required"/></td>'+
                '<td><input id="Size" type="text"  name="Size'+i+'"  maxlength="255" required="required"/></td>'+
                '<td><SELECT id="Type" name="Type'+i+'">'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="varchar">varchar</OPTION>'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="int">int</OPTION>'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="text">long</OPTION>'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="float">float</OPTION>'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="double">double</OPTION>'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="Date">Date</OPTION>'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="Time">Time</OPTION>'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="Year">Year</OPTION>'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="Real">Real</OPTION>'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="Boolean">Boolean</OPTION>'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="longText">longText</OPTION>'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="Binary">Binary</OPTION>'+
        '</SELECT></td>'+
        '<td><SELECT id="null" name="nullabilite'+i+'">'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="null">null</OPTION>'+
        '<OPTION VALUE="not_null">not_null</OPTION>'+
        '</SELECT></td>'+
        '</tr>').appendTo($("#tablona")).html()
            }

    </script>
```

I am getting an error on this line: `for(i=0;i<10;i++) {`
here's my stack trace:

```
2015-05-12 10:41:58.805 ERROR 1876 --- [ qtp13863100-20] o.thymeleaf.templateparser.ErrorHandler  : [THYMELEAF][qtp13863100-20] Fatal error during parsing

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Le contenu des éléments doit inclure un balisage ou des caractères au format correct.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.startOfMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.doParse(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:209)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingPool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:134)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplate(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:116)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2015-05-12 10:41:58.807 ERROR 1876 --- [ qtp13863100-20] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][qtp13863100-20] Exception processing template "result": Exception parsing document: template="result", line 28 - column 23
2015-05-12 10:41:58.812  WARN 1876 --- [ qtp13863100-20] o.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler   : 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="result", line 28 - column 23
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="result", line 28 - column 23
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingPool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplate(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:116)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Le contenu des éléments doit inclure un balisage ou des caractères au format correct.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.startOfMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.doParse(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:209)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingPool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:134)
    ... 43 common frames omitted

test1
{db=DetailsDatabase [Database_Name=null, Table_Name=null, field=null, size=0, type=null, nullabilité=null, columns_number=0]}
test3
test5
2015-05-12 10:50:36.556 ERROR 1876 --- [ qtp13863100-21] o.thymeleaf.templateparser.ErrorHandler  : [THYMELEAF][qtp13863100-21] Fatal error during parsing

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Le contenu des éléments doit inclure un balisage ou des caractères au format correct.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.startOfMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.doParse(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:209)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingPool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:134)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplate(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:116)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2015-05-12 10:50:36.558 ERROR 1876 --- [ qtp13863100-21] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][qtp13863100-21] Exception processing template "result": Exception parsing document: template="result", line 28 - column 23
2015-05-12 10:50:36.567  WARN 1876 --- [ qtp13863100-21] o.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler   : 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="result", line 28 - column 23
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="result", line 28 - column 23
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingPool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplate(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:116)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Le contenu des éléments doit inclure un balisage ou des caractères au format correct.
```

Comment: Move your script tag to before the end body tag, also you are duplicating ids in that piece of code, you may want to do the same as you do with the name: `id="field'+i+'"`

Comment: Please check the all tag which are close perfects or not

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried wrapping your inline code into CDATA section?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        // ...
    }
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I had the same issue and I resolved using CDATA section. Can you please explain to me what is CDATA ?

Comment: @Aguid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML, in short, it is a part of a XML document which should not be parsed as markup.